# R studio: use pivot_wider to pivot one column and reformat remaining columns

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot-table, tidyverse

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
+---------+---------+------+------+
| Date    | Channel | Var1 | Var2 |
+---------+---------+------+------+
| 2020-01 | Disney  | 100  | 10   |
+---------+---------+------+------+
| 2020-02 | Disney  | 200  | 20   |
+---------+---------+------+------+
| 2020-03 | Disney  | 300  | 30   |
+---------+---------+------+------+
| 2020-04 | Disney  | 400  | 40   |
+---------+---------+------+------+
| 2020-05 | Disney  | 500  | 50   |
+---------+---------+------+------+
| 2020-06 | Disney  | 600  | 60   |
+---------+---------+------+------+
| 2020-07 | Disney  | 700  | 70   |
+---------+---------+------+------+
| 2020-08 | Disney  | 800  | 80   |
+---------+---------+------+------+
| 2020-09 | Disney  | 900  | 90   |
+---------+---------+------+------+
| 2020-10 | Disney  | 1000 | 100  |
+---------+---------+------+------+
| 2020-11 | Disney  | 1100 | 110  |
+---------+---------+------+------+
| 2020-12 | Disney  | 1200 | 120  |
+---------+---------+------+------+
```

I would like to apply `pivot_wider` to the `Date` column, so that the dataframe would end up looking like this:

```
+---------+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Channel | Variable | 2020-01 | 2020-02 | 2020-03 | 2020-04 | 2020-05 | 2020-06 | 2020-07 | 2020-08 | 2020-09 | 2020-10 | 2020-11 | 2020-12 |
+---------+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Disney  | Var1     | 100     | 200     | 300     | 400     | 500     | 600     | 700     | 800     | 900     | 1000    | 1100    | 1200    |
+---------+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Disney  | Var2     | 10      | 20      | 30      | 40      | 50      | 60      | 70      | 80      | 90      | 100     | 110     | 12O     |
+---------+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I tried something like this:

```
data %>% pivot_wider(names_from = Date, values_from = c(Channel, Var1, Var2))
```

but it didn't yield the desired data output.

I am wondering what is an elegant way to transform this table using tidyverse?

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the data in long format first before using `pivot_wider` :

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(Var1, Var2)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Date, values_from = value)

# A tibble: 2 x 14
#   Channel name  `2020-01` `2020-02` `2020-03` `2020-04` `2020-05`
#  <chr>   <chr>     <int>     <int>     <int>     <int>     <int>
#1 Disney  Var1        100       200       300       400       500
#2 Disney  Var2         10        20        30        40        50
# … with 7 more variables: `2020-06` <int>, `2020-07` <int>,
#   `2020-08` <int>, `2020-09` <int>, `2020-10` <int>, `2020-11` <int>,
#   `2020-12` <int>
```

You can use `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)

dcast(melt(setDT(df), measure.vars = c("Var1", "Var2")), 
      Channel+variable~Date, value.var = 'value')
```